# INSERT INTO com filtro no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, filter, where

Estou tentando criar um INSERT INTO em um tabela X fazendo um filtro na tabela Y, mas recebo um erro de syntax. Pesquisei o que pode estar errado, mas não descobrir.

```
INSERT INTO products (
    SELECT * FROM products AS P
    WHERE P.FK_ID_QUOTE = 101
)
```

Comment: Qual seria o objetivo de se colocar um "where" no insert?

Comment: Eu quero especificar em qual id da tabela quote eu quero adicionar o que eu filtrei

Comment: Você quer duplicar um registro mudando o id?

Comment: se entendi o comentário a ideia é alterar um registro, não incluir um novo... não?

Comment: Não. Criei uma função para duplicar uma 'quote' com um novo id, mas preciso copiar todos os produtos da quote de referência para a nova quote.
Essa query que eu postei está errada. Vou editar.
Mas o que preciso é copiar os produtos do filtro com novos id e associar a quote duplicada.
No final desejo que tudo seja duplicado com ids novos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Onde está colocando a consulta tem que especificar as colunas que quer copiar e depois vem os valores que podem ser obtidos pela seleção, algo assim:

```
INSERT INTO products (nome, valor, etc)
    SELECT nome, valor, etc FROM products AS P
    WHERE P.FK_ID_QUOTE = 101
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/WithSelect.sql).

Answer (score 2):

A solução seria fazer uma subquery, conforme abaixo:

Criei a tabela PESSOA_2, que quero inserir dados nela conforme a tabela PESSOA:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso, a query para inserir em PESSOA_2 ficaria:

```
INSERT INTO PESSOA_2 (IDADE, ID_PESSOA, NOME, DATA_NASC) 
SELECT 15, ID_PESSOA, NOME, DATA_NASC FROM PESSOA WHERE IDADE = 20;
```

O resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]